# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named (moduleName) even though in PYTHONPATH and __init__.py present

Tags: python, importerror

Given the following `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/git/bluej/mobile/python:/git/bluej/fusion/python
```

And verifying that `webhandler` exists:

```
ls -lrta /git/bluej/mobile/python/pointr/bluej/mobile

-rw-rw-r-- 1 pointr pointr  2104 Feb 12 03:04 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pointr pointr 17578 Feb 14 22:40 webhandler.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pointr pointr  4275 Feb 14 22:40 http_listeners.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 pointr pointr  4096 Feb 14 22:40 .
drwxrwxr-x 2 pointr pointr  4096 Feb 14 22:41 __pycache__
```

Let's run a script containing the following import

```
from pointr.bluej.mobile.webhandler import MobileSopListener
```

Here is the command line

```
python3 pointr/bluej/fusion/json_generators.py $1
```

But the import is not working:

```
File "pointr/bluej/fusion/json_generators.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pointr.bluej.mobile.webhandler import MobileSopListener
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pointr.bluej.mobile'
```

I am uncertain why it is not found. This is `python 3.7` on `ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS`.   Tips?

**Update** per suggestion by @S3DEV the following was added the `json_generators.py` target script:

```
sys.path.append("/git/bluej/mobile/python")
```

I also tried

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/git/bluej/mobile/python")
```

Neither of these had an effect: same error.

*Another update* Per (good) question by @Sraw: there are `__init__.py`' in the entire path of the imported/target:

```
 pwd
 /git/bluej/mobile/python$

 find . -name __init__.py
./pointr/__init__.py
./pointr/bluej/__init__.py
./pointr/bluej/mobile/__init__.py
```

Comment: It's a bit tricky having imports from parallel(ish) paths.  Does my head in.  Check your sys.path, and maybe insert the pointr.bluej.mobile path there too.

Comment: @S3DEV thx for that tip: will try it and report back

Comment: I added it in: did not have any effect (question updated as well)

Comment: Rather than append, use sys.path.insert(0, '/the_path').  Python searches this list in order when importing libs.  (Worth a shot; usually fixes the issue when I have this problem). Obviously, add this statement before the import statement.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` file inside every directory through the path `pointr/bluej/mobile`? It might not be the case but worth a try.

Comment: @Sraw  good point.  I had actually already added those `__init__.py` all the way back to root - just in case. Have updated question with that info

Comment: @S3DEV  Made the change `sys.path.insert(0,"/git/bluej/mobile/python")`  but no effect

Comment: I'll await further ideas: but in meantime I bulk copied the source files into the same parent directory (that works)

Comment: I think you at least can do a debugging. First `import pointr`, and then check `pointr.__file__`. If it is correct, then `from pointr import bluej` and check `bluej.__file__`, etc. Hope it will help.